# vb6:Dynamically changing Combo box to text box

Tags: vb6

I have a form with a combo box. Currently It displays the available values from the database. But for a particular scenario, I wants it dynamically change to a text box so that the user can manually enter the value. Can I do it in the same form. If I use a second form,I can solve this problem. But I want to do it with little code changes. Can someone provide some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You can set `DropDownStyle` to `DropDown`.</strike>
My bad. Indeed, in vb6 the style property can't be changed during runtime.

1. You can hide/show desired control.
2. Try using `Locked` property.

Comment: thanks. I tried to change the style property for the combo box in vb6 during runtime. But It seems like it is read only.

Comment: I think Przeszczep meant using two controls, hiding/showing them at the need.

Answer (score 0):

I used a combo array(combobox(0),combobox(1)) with two different styles(**simple combo and dropdowncombo)** and made it visible and disable at runtime using the **Visible** property